# Heroku web app in Python with strange error

Tags: python, heroku, deployment

This is the error that I get on my Python web app on Heroku.
It serves an `index.html` page with a form. The user compiles it and then the app must give him an html response.

But while serving the response page I get the error below. What does it mean?

> ```
> 2015-09-06T16:23:36.333232+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H25 desc="HTTP restriction: oversized status line" method=POST
> ```
>
> path="/response.html" host=stantool.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=b9902c0f-d2d1-4cd7-a039-ce1920031d51 fwd="95.232.75.72"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=15445ms status=502 bytes=9640

I think that I understood the error but I have no idea of how I can fix it...

I think that the problem is that in my index.html I have this code

```
  <form method=POST name="sentMessage" id="annucioForm" action="response.html" novalidate>
```

The file `index.html` is served by a Python script

```
if self.path == '/':
    self.path = 'tool/public/index.html'

logging.warning(self.headers)
SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)
```

Than I create a response in this way:

```
header=""
        in_file = open(utily.get_full_path("public/header.html"),"r")
        header = in_file.read()
        in_file.close()



        footer=""
        in_file = open(utily.get_full_path("public/footer.html"),"r")
        footer = in_file.read()
        in_file.close()


        html_to_serve=""
        in_file = open(utily.get_full_path("public/response_"+tipologia_prodotto+".html"),"r")
        html_to_serve = in_file.read()
        in_file.close()
```

And I serve it in this way:

```
    logging.warning("======= POST STARTED =======")
    #logging.warning(self.headers)
    form = cgi.FieldStorage(
        fp=self.rfile,
        headers=self.headers,
        environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST',
                 'CONTENT_TYPE':self.headers['Content-Type'],
                 })
    logging.warning("======= POST VALUES =======")

 self.wfile.write((header+html_to_serve+footer).encode('utf-8'))
```

But the form page in the index.html redirect to a page called response.html that doesn't exist.

How can I solve it? I think that the problem is in the form of the `index.html` page

Comment: 502 is the error status code for bad gateway. Does the initial `index.html` page with the form serve correctly?

Comment: Can you show your code that returns the response.

Comment: H25 means an issue with the response status

Comment: Hello Guys! I have added a lot of info I think that I understood the problem but I have no idea of how can I fix it

Comment: i think you are not sending any http headers.